# How to find exceptions in recursion

Tags: java, exception, recursion, try-catch, stack-overflow

How can I try and catch the exception in this recursion?

this is the code:

```
try
    { 
    public static long faktoral(long a)
    {
      return a*faktoral(a-1);  
    }
    }
    catch(exception e){
           System.out.print(e.message());
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.print(faktoral(3));
    }
```

Comment: welcome. Please when you ask a question include details about the error you had. A traceback with actual exception text is usually useful to people trying to answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are exceeding your maximum recursion depth, right?

A recursive functinon needs to have some way of escaping....

Have some pseudocode:

```
function faktoral(a):
    if a<0:
        raise Exception ("negative")
    if a<=1:
        return 1
    return a*faktoral(a-1)
```

If you think about what your current code does, line by line, you will see why I added the extra if statements.

if I call `faktoral(2)` with your code your function will try to return:

```
2*faktoral(1) which is:
2*1*faktoral(0) which is:
2*1*0*factoral(-1)
etc
```

the corrected code will return:

```
2*faktoral(1) which is:
2*1
2
```